# input name not correct MVC EditorTemplate For Array

Tags: asp.net-mvc

my Code is

```
public class TarkibVM:BaseVM
{
    public int TarkibID { get;set;}

    [UIHint("KhorakTarkibList")]
    public KhorakTarkibVM[] KhorakTarkibVms { get; set; }}


public class KhorakTarkibVM
{
    public int KhorakID{ get;set;}

    public string Name{ get;set;}
}
```

KhorakTarkibList.cshtml :

```
@model MvcMarkazToyoor.Models.KhorakTarkibVM[]

<table>

@for (int index = 0; index < Model.Count(); index++)
{
    <tr>
        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem[index])
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

KhorakTarkibVM.cshtml :

```
@model MvcMarkazToyoor.Models.KhorakTarkibVM

<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.Checked)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.KhorakID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.KhorakID)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Name)
</td>
```

Create.cshtml :

```
@model MvcMarkazToyoor.Models.TarkibVM

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GroupID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TarkibID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TarkibID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KhorakTarkibVms)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>}
```

in this code all thing is Ok , except name of array input no correct
I expect name="KhorakTarkibVms[0].Percent"
but generated name is name="KhorakTarkibVms.[0].Percent"

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1-** you can't use Array in this situations, instead use `List<>`

**2-** don't need iterate `KhorakTarkibVms` so don't need `KhorakTarkibList.cshtml`

So this is new `TarkibVM` class:

```
public int TarkibID { get; set; }
public int GroupID { get; set; }
public List<KhorakTarkibVM> KhorakTarkibVms { get; set; }
```

Don't remember delete `KhorakTarkibList.cshtml` or rename it or remove `UIhintAttribute`.

Don't iterate `KhorakTarkibVms`, So new `Create.cshtml` is:

```
@model MvcMarkazToyoor.Models.TarkibVM

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GroupID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TarkibID)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TarkibID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
       <table>
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KhorakTarkibVms)
       </table>
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
}
```

Add tr tag in new `KhorakTarkibVM.cshtml`:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.Checked)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.KhorakID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.KhorakID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Name)
    </td>
</tr>
```